# Deadlock with a very simple query

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, deadlock

I have a service which inserts and updates rows from a table.

The problem starts when somebody launches 20 calls to the service at the same time, resulting in some of the transactions getting rolledback with a deadlock error.

```
 "Transaction (Process ID) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction."
```

The thing about this is that my queries are not logically able to suffer a deadblock.

My service has 4 different queries, but we can ignore 2 of them as they are single-row inserts which don't lock any rows as they don't need to.

The other 2 queries are this ones:

```
UPDATE Documents SET read = 1 WHERE id = ?
```

and

```
UPDATE Documents SET name = ?, title = ? WHERE id = ?
```

There are NO two rows with the same id, so I don't understand how is possible to a interblock to occur.

I am using statements:

```
try {

            PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement(updateQuery);
            st.setString(1, true);
            int rowsUpdated = st.executeUpdate();

            if(rowsUpdated == 0) {


                st = con.prepareStatement(insertQuery);

                    st.setString(1, "example");
                    [...]
                    st.executeUpdate();


            }
```

I'm using SQL Server 2016, the `sqljdbc4` library. I can provide any further info that could help.

Comment: The deadlock's xml-report would be helpful. It can be taken from `system_health` extended events session.

Comment: Also provide the DDL, including indexes for the table.  Deadlocks can occur on non-clustered indexes, and on related tables affected by cascading foreign keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to index the columns in the `where` clause.

It seems that the query was blocking all the rows while `SCANNING` instead of `SEEKING` a particular row.